# How to use variable string text to access JSON array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I am using a movie API which first give a ID **{also gives the title of the movie}** on the basis of movie title and then we can access the movie data from that ID.

[image]

**As you can see the result consists of an array which is actually the title of the movie I am getting.**
[image]

So, I am getting the ID and title but to access its data I need to use its title. If I am unable to make you understand , here's an image

[image]

So I want to use the value of title to get year from the JSON but I am unable to do that.
[image: And this is the error]

Comment: Please give us your entire response structure

Comment: any specific reason for that? I mean I just need to use the value of title while getting data from JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
var year = data.content[title]
```

Comment: Ok mistake was from my side..It worked now!